# Problema ao fazer o Deploy de aplicação Spring Boot

Tags: maven, deploy, spring-boot, build

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Spring Boot e Thymeleaf e ao tentar gerar o .jar que deve ser executado no servidor, ele até gera tudo certinho, mas ocorre um erro ao tentar acessar a pagina que está em `/resouces/templates/admin/home.html`.

O problema é que, executando o método `main` para subir a aplicação na minha IDE, ele funciona de boa, ou seja, me retorna as paginas htmls com thymeleaf e funfa legal, mas quando eu gero o .jar com o mvn me retorna a seguinte exceção:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/admin/home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Meu pom.xml tem essas informações:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     -->

    <!-- Conexão com o Postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Acredito que o problema seja a local onde estão os seus templates. Você colocou eles em *src/main/resources/templates*?

Comment: Qual o comando que você executou para gerar o jar?

Answer (score 0):

O problema esta na localização do seu template, veja [aqui](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html), em particular essa parte:

*IntelliJ IDEA orders the classpath differently depending on how you run your application. Running your application in the IDE via its main method will result in a different ordering to when you run your application using Maven or Gradle or from its packaged jar. This can cause Spring Boot to fail to find the templates on the classpath. If you’re affected by this problem you can reorder the classpath in the IDE to place the module’s classes and resources first. Alternatively, you can configure the template prefix to search every templates directory on the classpath: classpath*:/templates/.*